# How can I delete a chat room I've made?

Tags: support

I've created a chat room which not belongs to Drupal. Just I realized that I've created it in wrong place. I need to delete the created [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20109/how-to-get-ssl-certificate-type-of-a-domain).

My question belongs to [Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) so it should be created [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=unix.stackexchange.com)??

Is there any way to delete the room I've made? or any option to flag that for moderator attention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could flag one of the messages for moderation attention, but (as the dialog box says), that should be used for serious issues that require moderator's attention.

> [image: screenshot]

> [image: screenshot]

You could post in the meta site for the site where the chat room was created, as you did in this case, or you could go in a chat room where you can find a moderator of a Stack Exchange site. Elected moderators and pro-temp moderators for a .stackexchange.com site are also moderators on chat.stackexchange.com, and they can delete the room you created, although the user who created it is always able to delete it, as room owner.

Answer (score 2):

You should have been able to delete that room as you automatically became room owner when you created it. There should be an option delete under the room menu in the sidebar.

The room would have also been deleted automatically after a while as it didn't contain enough messages to be kept forever.

I've just removed that room now anyway.